# How to find the next sequence in binary arithmetically?

Tags: binary

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhln9.png

From the given array data structure and if the base address is 010 base2 at position 0, how do you find the next sequence in binary in order to find the memory address of a specific position? I don't know how 1 = 011 base 2, 2 = 100 base 2, 3 = 101 base 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> the base address is 010 base2 ... I don't know how 1 = 011 base 2, 2 = 100 base 2, 3 = 101 base 2, etc.

It appears there's just an offset of +2 to what's otherwise an ordinary sequence.
`binary 000, 001, 010, 011... + decimal 2` = `binary 010, 011, 100, 101...`
Just add 2 before you convert to binary and you should have the right location.